# BizTalk: How to promote 2 fields in custom pipeline?

Tags: filter, properties, biztalk, pipeline

I'm trying to write a custom pipeline that will promote 2 fields on my map so that the concatenation of those 2 fields could be blocked in the filter, I have a list of words that needs to be blocked.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: But you don't need a custom pipeline or component to promote properties.

Comment: How can you promote 2 values that you needs to be joined then?

Answer (score 0):

> How can you promote 2 values that you needs to be joined then?

1. Set them up as regular Promoted Properties.
2. Write a custom Pipeline Component to run *after* the Xml Disassembler to read those Properties and Write/Promote the third Property.

**Important Note:**  In the custom Pipeline Component, you must ensure the entire stream has been read by the XmlDisassembler to guarantee the Propeties have been Promoted.  You can do this by just copying the incoming stream to a new stream and resetting the pointer back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

1 . You need write in Custom Pipeline

2. Write a custom Pipeline Component to run after the Xml Disassembler.
3. After code below promove properties in your Custom Pipeline.

outMessage.Context.Promote("MessageType", systemPropertiesNamespace, namespaceURI );